# Behavior of NSData initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I want to have a fix length mutable content shared data buffer and that is how do I create it:

```
void *buffer = malloc(length);
// initialize buffer content
NSData *sharedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:length freeWhenDone:YES]
```

What happen if I modify `buffer` after I created a NSData from it?  Will NSData reflect the change I did to `buffer`?

I can guaranty that `sharedData` will not get dealloc when I want to modify `buffer`.

This is how I actually want to use it:

---

```
void *my_alloc(CFIndex allocSize, CFOptionFlags hint, void *info) {return NULL;}
void my_dealloc(void *ptr, void *info) {
    mach_vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (mach_vm_address_t)ptr, (size_t)info);
}
```

---

```
size_t length = //some number
mach_vm_address_t buffer;
mach_vm_allocate(mach_task_self(), &buffer, length, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
// do something to buffer, for example pass to other process using mach RPC and expect other process will modify the content
CFAllocatorContext context = {0, (void *)length, NULL, NULL, NULL, my_alloc, NULL, my_dealloc, NULL};
CFAllocatorRef allocator = CFAllocatorCreate(NULL, &context);
CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(NULL, (const UInt8 *)buffer, length, allocator);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `initWithBytesNoCopy:` will effectively create an `NSData` wrapper around the existing buffer; so yes, things accessing through `[sharedData bytes]` will see any updates you make.

Of course, it does nothing to link other objects which are created from the `NSData` instance, so for instance an `[NSImage initWithData:sharedData]` may make a copy for the `NSImage` instance, which won't reflect any changes.

Also, with `freeWhenDone:YES` the `NSData` will destroy the buffer when the last reference is removed, so look out for that =)

---

So, given that the `NSData` is effectively a thin wrapper around a `malloc()` allocation, yes it will reflect changes made to that memory (by any process); but as it will call `free()` on it, it's a bad idea to use it to wrap a buffer created another way (`mach_vm_allocate`) with `freeWhenDone:YES`.

If you don't really-really need to use a custom allocator (why?), I think you'd be better off with:

```
NSMutableData* sharedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:length];
// `dataWithLength:` will fully allocate and zero the buffer first, if you prefer
void* buffer = [sharedData mutableBytes];
// do something to `buffer`, mach RPC, etc.
// 3: profit.
```