# Converting C-types to Objective-C objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I have two questions.

1. How to create a NSFileHandle object with the FILE* instance?
2. How to create a NSData object with the void* instance?

I am sorry there's little information without context.

Just refer to my recent question. [Weird behavior of fopen on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749369/weird-behavior-of-fopen-on-ios/9759112#9759112) I cannot use the native fopen function to create or to write the content into a file.

As a result, I just want to use the api in the ios framework and wrap the code of fopen and fwrite and such staff. So I should convert the FILE* object into NSFileHandle or something that can manipulate the file. Also the content which is handled with void* should be converted to the data format that can be accepted in the ios framework. And I think NSData should be the choice.

Comment: Some more information? Context?

Comment: @TheDeveloper Sorry, I had updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for FILE* to NSFileHandle, I found this [mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Mar/msg01943.html) question that perfectly matches what you need.  Relevant code:

```
FILE *fp;
NSFileHandle *p;

fp = fopen( "foo", "r");
p = [[[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fileno( fp)
closeOnDealloc:YES] autorelease];
```

And it comes with a lovely warning from the answerer:

> Be careful not to read from fp, because stdio caches.

EDIT: As for void* to NSData, I think you want `NSData's -initWithBytesNoCopy:Length:freeWhenDone:`.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691997/behavior-of-nsdata-initwithbytesnocopylengthfreewhendone) on how to use it.

Comment: I think this may be helpful. I will try first.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use FILE* like you do in C.  For example...

```
- (id)initWithFileUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[url path] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:0];

        char const *path = [fileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:url.path];
        fp = fopen(path, "a");
        if (!fp) {
            [NSException raise:@"Can't open file for recording: " format:@"%s", strerror(errno)];
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)writeBytes:(void const *)bytes length:(uint32_t)size
{
    if (fp && fwrite(bytes, size, 1, fp) != 1) {
        [NSException raise:@"File Write Error" format:@"%s", strerror(errno)];
    }
}
- (void)writeBytes:(void const *)bytes andSize:(uint32_t)size
{
    if (!fp) return;
    if (fwrite(&size, sizeof size, 1, fp) != 1 || fwrite(bytes, size, 1, fp) != 1) {
        [NSException raise:@"File Write Error" format:@"%s", strerror(errno)];
    }
}
- (void)writeInt32:(int32_t)value
{
    [self writeBytes:&value length:sizeof value];
}
- (void)writeInt64:(int64_t)value
{
    [self writeBytes:&value length:sizeof value];
}
- (void)writeData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self writeBytes:data.bytes andSize:data.length];
}
- (void)writeCGFloat:(CGFloat)value
{
    [self writeBytes:&value length:sizeof value];
}
- (void)writeCGPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    [self writeBytes:&point length:sizeof(point)];
}
```

Comment: I had tried to solve my problem in this way. But when fwrite calls, it gave me an error log and said invalid sandbox. I don't know why.

Comment: I snipped this from a project of mine, and it's been working fine for a long time.  I saw your other thread.  Looks like maybe you were not using the proper method to create the file system string.